# Program must decide positive, negative, or zero

Tags: c++

I need to desigen a program which it must display positive, negative or zero when user enter the number with a function name called numtest. when i enter number 0 it still appears as, number negative. Can anyone help me on this. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


float numtest(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if(a>1)
    return a;

    if(b<1)
    return b;

    if(c=0)
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    float num;
    cout<<"Please enter number";
    cin>>num;

    if(num>1)
    cout<<"number is positive";

    if(num<1)
    cout<<"number is negative";

    if(num=0)
    cout<<"number is zero";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(c=0)` doesn't do what you think it does. Also don't compare `float` or `double` values for equalty directly.

Comment: Hint: negative means "less than zero".

Comment: About `c=0`, your compiler should warn you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when checking equality you must use `==` instead of `=`.The `=` sign assigns the R.H.S. to the L.H.S. Eg. `c=0` changes the value in `c` to be `0`, so instead it should be `if(c==0)`.

Now, if you want to check positive numbers, the condition should be `if(num>0)`, and for negative numbers, it should be `if(num<0)`.

Lastly, try to use `else if` and `else` instead of three `ifs`.

Comment: 'for negative numbers, it should be if(num>0)' I think you made a typo, should be `num<0`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've made the age old problem of assigning a 0 to num when you want an equality comparison.

```
if(num == 0){ ... }
```

Also, think of what happens when you enter 0.5 or -0.5. And in your question you mention using your function (numtest) to do something, but your not even calling it in your main function

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue would be solved if you changed your parameters to:

```
if(a>0)
```

`if(a==)`

`if a<0)`

Because they way you have it set now you are not accounting for the infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1 (.10 , .0000005 , etc). And we want to use the "==" sign to so equality.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not using the `numtest()` function and unwanted variable used and for testing number is +ve or -ve you should use

For Positive:  `if(num>0)` or `if(num>=1)` in case of float`if(num>=0.001)`

For Negative: `if(num<0)` or `if(num<=-1)` in case of float`if(num>=-0.01)`

For Zero:      `if(num==0)`

Try the below program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>


void numtest(float num)
{
if(num>0)
cout<<"number is positive";

if(num<0)
cout<<"number is negative";

if(num==0)
cout<<"number is zero";
}

void main()
{
float n;
cout<<"Please enter number";
cin>>n;

numtest(n);

getch();

}
```